# I want to replicate this chart that shows how companies change quintiles over time

Tags: r, ggplot2, charts

I am trying replicate the below chart (see hyperlink) taken from the Grattan institute in Australia. I have a list of ~200 fund managers who I have split into quintiles (by funds under management) for the years 2009 and 2019.

I want to be able to show how many fund managers in each quintile in 2009 are in the 1,2,3,4 & 5 quintile in 2019 (and which ones have ceased operation).

I cannot find any similar examples of this kind of chart online.

Can anyone recommend me code - i have tried several versions using scatter plots but its not the same.

Much appreciated!!!

[image: grattan_institute]

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sankey/index.html

Comment: Looks like a parallel coordinates plot. Maybe try the `ggparcoord` function from GGally or ggparallel packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of plot is called an 'alluvial' plot (or chart), metaphorically referring to the alluvial-like 'flow' that it appears to depict.

There is an R package 'alluvial', as well as 'ggalluvial' as an extension to ggplot2, designed to plot exactlty these.

See:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/alluvial/vignettes/alluvial.html

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggalluvial/vignettes/ggalluvial.html

Comment: Thanks Dominic, this is exactly what i need